# What number should be placed in that last slot?

Tags: puzzle

[image]

I came across a very difficult puzzle. What number should be placed in that last slot? I only know 16 is not the correct answer, because 11 is before 10.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the game ...

Comment: This should be put on puzzling.stackexchange, if anywhere.

Comment: The correct answer is 18, but I don't know why and how to make that conclusion.

Comment: At least , in this puzzle , there is a little context (the famous $15$-puzzle), but still there are surely several possibilities for the missing entry that can be well justified.

Answer (score 0):

The $6$ and $9$ are upside-down, and this restores the parity (of the sliding block puzzle).